# Issues with SD card reader

Tags: drivers, sd-card, dell-vostro, card-reader

I have a DELL VOSTRO SSF PC with a frontal SD card reader.

When I attach my SD card, the drive unit is normally shown in windows, but I cannot change the letter of the unit.
The change letter button on "disk management" is simply disabled.

If I use an external reader it is enabled. What it depends on? Is there any way to change the drive letter with the integrated reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to the "lock" switch.
Inserting an SD in this DELL VOSTRO reader the switch is always moved to lock due to the tightness of the reader... it is incredible. I had to put a piece of tape in the card.

Comment: Bonus points if the card slot surreptitiously slides the lock switch back when removing the card.

Comment: This feature will be added in the new Dell Vostro serie